# Update data table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, proxy

I am creating a shiny application that has various plots in it. It also includes a table that updates with user's date range specification. This works great, but when I initially load the application there is a blank spot where the table should be. Ideally, I would like this blank space to have a sample of the dataset displaying before the user even updates the date range specification or clicks the submit button. Is there a way to do this in shiny? I've tried dataTableProxy(), but did not find success. Here is a sample of my code and data.

Sample Data:

```
County        State Case   Count   Death Count
Cook          Illinois     18451   99
Los Angeles   California   15704   167
El Paso       Texas        11713   37
Maricopa      Arizona      6456    54
Tarrant       Texas        6448    42
Harris        Texas        6219    71
Salt Lake     Utah         6216    18
Milwaukee     Wisconsin    6057    29
Miami-Dade    Florida      5943    87
Clark         Nevada       5384    38
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)

## Reads data
temp <- read.csv()

## Creates Initial Table 
table0 <- head(temp[order(temp$Count, decreasing = TRUE),], 10)

ui <- fluidPage(      

  ## Application title
  titlePanel("Project"),
  tags$hr(),
  ## Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date Range:",
                     start = as.character(Sys.Date() - 6),
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date()),
                     min = "2020-01-22",
                     max = Sys.Date()),
      checkboxInput("checkBox", "Select all dates", FALSE),
      textOutput("dateCheck"),
      selectInput("typeChoice", "Data Type:", choices = c("Raw", "Percentage")),
      actionButton("submitButton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(tableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (input$checkBox == TRUE){
      updateDateRangeInput(session,
                           "daterange",
                           "Date Range:",
                           start = "2020-01-22",
                           end = Sys.Date(),
                           min = "2020-01-22",
                           max = Sys.Date())
    }
  })
  
  ## Displays Initial Table
  output$table <- renderTable(table0)
    
  observeEvent(input$submitButton, {
    
    ## Updates data ##
    if (input$typeChoice == "Raw"){
      df <- selectdates(start = input$daterange[1], end = input$daterange[2])
      df$Total <- df$Count_Sum
    } else if (input$typeChoice == "Percentage"){
      df <- selectdates(start = input$daterange[1], end = input$daterange[2])
      df$Total <- df$Perc_Sum
    } else {return(NULL)}
    
    df <- df[order(df$`Variable of Interest`, decreasing = TRUE),]
    df <- df[, -c(1, 4, 5, 9)]
    df$`Case Count` <- as.integer(df$`Count`)
    df$`Death Count` <- as.integer(df$`Death Count`)

    ## THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ##
    ## Trying to update table with click of button ##    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        head(df[order(df$Count, decreasing = TRUE),], 10)
    })

  })  
}

## Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data as the output of `dput`, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a `reactiveValues` object to display and define `output$table` only once.  You can update the dataframe in the observeEvent as shown below.  Also, you may need to update your `filter`.

```
## Reads data
#temp <- read.csv()

temp<- gapminder[1:1000,]
temp$Count <- temp$fertility
temp$Count_Sum <- temp$population
temp$Perc_Sum  <- temp$life_expectancy

temp <- as.data.frame(temp)

## Creates Initial Table 
table0 <- head(temp[order(temp$Count, decreasing = TRUE),], 10)

ui <- fluidPage(      
  
  ## Application title
  titlePanel("Project"),
  tags$hr(),
  ## Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date Range:",
                     start = as.character(Sys.Date() - 6),
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date()),
                     min = "1920-01-22",
                     max = Sys.Date()),
      checkboxInput("checkBox", "Select all dates", FALSE),
      textOutput("dateCheck"),
      selectInput("typeChoice", "Data Type:", choices = c("Raw", "Percentage")),
      actionButton("submitButton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(tableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  observe({
    DF1$data <- table0
    if (input$checkBox == TRUE){
      updateDateRangeInput(session,
                           "daterange",
                           "Date Range:",
                           start = "2020-01-22",
                           end = Sys.Date(),
                           min = "1920-01-22",
                           max = Sys.Date())
    }
  })
  
  ## Displays Initial Table
  output$table <- renderTable(DF1$data)
  
  observeEvent(input$submitButton, {
    
    ## Updates data ##
    if (input$typeChoice == "Raw"){
      df <- temp # %>% filter(year, between(year, input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2]))
      df$Total <- df$Count_Sum
    } else if (input$typeChoice == "Percentage"){
      df <- temp # %>% filter(year, between(year, input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2]))
      #df <- selectdates(start = input$daterange[1], end = input$daterange[2])
      df$Total <- df$Perc_Sum
    } else {return(NULL)}
    
    #df <- df[order(df$`Variable of Interest`, decreasing = TRUE),]
    #df <- df[, -c(1, 4, 5, 9)]
    #df$`Case Count` <- as.integer(df$`Count`)
    #df$`Death Count` <- as.integer(df$`Death Count`)
    
    ## THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ##
    ## Trying to update table with click of button ##    
    DF1$data <- df
    # output$table <- renderTable({
    #   head(df[order(df$Count, decreasing = TRUE),], 10)
    # })
    
  })  
}

## Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```